# How to stop the 'd' key from minimizing all windows in Ubuntu 10.10 when connected with Nomachine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, macos, xorg, nx

When I connect to my Ubuntu box from any Mac OS X 10.6 client (Snow Leopard) using Nomachine, the 'd' key minimizes all windows on my Ubuntu box. I found [another post here](https://serverfault.com/questions/197833/nx-server-lower-case-d-minimizes-from-os-x-client) that says the issue can be fixed by changing some settings on the Ubuntu box when connected. However, I cannot find the location of the settings indicated in that post.

Does anyone know how to resolve this 'd' key problem?

Comment: Please read our FAQ so you know what's appropriate for this site and what's more likely to be answered on our sister sites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default Ubuntu maps the "show desktop" command to the `Super`+`D` key combination. The `Super` key is also sometimes known as the `Windows` key. While I've never used Nomachine, my assumption would be that it is having an issue with the `Super` key as it does not exist on your Mac. I would try changing that key binding on the Ubuntu side.

Go to `System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`

[image: keyboard shortcuts]

Find the entry titled "Hide all normal windows and set focus to the desktop" and try a new keyboard combination.

Comment: this fixed me when I was having the problem logging into my Ubuntu 10.10 via windows RDP into the default Ubuntu RDP service (on port 3389 apparently and tunnels into 5900??).  thanks.